# How to retrieve all data in rally

Tags: java, rally

I know that there is a rally REST API at:https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice (access this site need username and password), But I don't know how to use it. Is there anybody tell me how to use it in Java?

Comment: Could you refine your question to be more specific? 

Instead of staging your question like this: I want to do 'X'; tell me how to do 'X'.

Consider amending: I'm trying to do 'X' and I have encountered problem 'A'; how do I resolve 'A'

Comment: Thank you for your advice. the scene is that I want to get all the data in rally to load it in a file or database, and then use the data warehouse technology to get a report. So I want to know how to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Rally REST Toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava).  Become familiar with the object model in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) documentation since the toolkit works in the context of Web Services API. For example, if you want to know attributes a user story (referred to as HierarchicalRequirement in the WS API) the place to look is WS API documentation, and not the user guide for the toolkit.

The toolkit's [user guide](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide) has an example that  illustrates how to create, update, read, query and delete using the RallyRestApi object.